# Registration screen never results in a successful task

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I programmed a registration page, but any instance shows that the registration is unsuccessful.

I've tried switching around the if, else statements, but it always results in an unsuccessful registration even after I cleared the firebase database.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignUp.this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authentication was unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Intent switchToMainActivity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sign up was successful!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(switchToMainActivity);

                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Here is the code for the activity

Comment: Do task.getException() and print the message from exception here

Comment: Yes please check and debug by doing task.getException() and also make sure internet is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is looking solid so far, I cannot see any error there. Please log the error message, firebase gives you:

```
if(!task.isSuccessful()){
    FirebaseAuthException exception = (FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()
    Log.e("ErrorLogTag", exception)
}
```